# CSS: php messing up template css due to css link

Tags: html, css

My php page styling is done but when I added it to my existing html template ( which has header and left menu ) I noticed that template css menu is messed up.

While debugging what part of styling is causing an issue, I realized its due to bootstrap.min.css which I used while referring to w3schools [BootStrap Progress Bar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar6&stacked=h):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Any pointers on how to avoid this? I thought of adding a wrapping container for code but not sure how to make the change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please post some more of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult issue to solve as bootstrap has a lot of default styling. The only thing I can recommend is:

1. Be sure that your styles come after the inclusion of the bootstrap stylesheet. This way your styles will overwrite bootstraps styles where there are conflicts.
2. If this does not fix the issue you will probably have to use the code inspector to find all instances that you think are incorrect and override them in your own stylesheet. This will be tedius, but if you want to use bootstrap and you have conflicts it may be your only option.
3. Bootstrap used to have a customizer allowing you to download only what you want, but it seems that in version 4 it is a little more complicated to do this. If you are already using version 3.3 then I would recommend downloading a customized version: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Comment: Thanks @Robert for the suggestions. Looks like I will go with approach #2.

Comment: 3 days of struggle and finally got it working with option #2. Thanks a lot